# Audio powering off for GTX 670

Tags: sound, power

My audio keeps turning off unless there is a sound playing. I'm using a GTX 670 using HDMI to my monitor. Is this a power saving feature? If so, how can I turn it off?

Comment: What graphic driver works on your system?
Have you already changed to nvidia 346.82?

Comment: I don't know if this a power-saving feature. But you can try a test.
Enter the word alsamixer into the Terminal and put all the controller to maximum. Control this by arrow-keys.

Comment: Maxed out the gain in aslamixer, no change. I'm just using whatever driver installed by default.

Comment: Why do you mean by powering off.